# How to match an array against another array query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say I have a collection that has documents like this where the crossRefs field is an array of strings:

```
{ name: "joe", crossRefs: [ "1" , "2" , "10a"] }
{ name: "jane", crossRefs: [ "10a" , "0xfgh" , "9"] }
{ name: "john", crossRefs: [ "11" , "hhj12" , "13dd"] }
...
```

**Question 1: How to build a query against crossRefs with an array of strings**

I would like to have a query that says "give me all the documents that have **any one of** crossRefs '10a', '1' and '2'". So the result from the above 3 documents would be just the first 2. I'm thinking I need `$elemMatch` or `$in` with a combination of `or`s but I just don't know how to formulate this.

**Question 2: How to specify an index**

I would like for MongoDB to build an index based on the crossRefs field. In Java is this as simple as:

```
mainDB.getCollection("theCollection").ensureIndex("crossRefs");
```

I.e. does that work ok when the field is actually an array of strings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$in` works with [array fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) as well as non-array fields, so in the shell it would be:

```js
db.theCollection.find({crossRefs: {$in: ['10a', '1', '2']}})
```

This will find the docs where at least one `crossRefs` element matches an `$in` element.

And yes, that's the correct way to index the field, even when it's an array.